# Some functionalities stop working after closing VSCode

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, antd, ng-zorro-antd

my project was working fine until I went from angular 9 to 10. After several attempts to manage dependencies, I ran git reset --soft HEAD ~ 1 to recover the version that worked but finally I completely deleted the project and cloned it again from the repository.

The problem now is that each time I close VSCode and I reopen it some functions stop working (automatic closing of the drawer, timeLine ...)

When I remove package-lock.json and node_modules then I run npm install it works again but once VSCode is closed the same problem.

N.B: I use NG-ZORRO

Answer (score 0):

I feel your pain, npm is really difficult to work with. There is a great website from Angular to help you update, guiding you step by step - https://update.angular.io/

Have you tried running the repo in VSCode on a different PC to make sure it's not the repo?

You can uninstall node, then remove npm and npm-cache from AppData\Roaming, and even VSCode (remove AppData\Roaming\Code folder too) since it is quick and easy to reinstall. I would then reboot.

Then

1. install node
2. from the c:\ root directory, open command prompt
3. type - npm install -g @angular/cli
4. clone the repo and try again

Note you still don't have VSCode installed at this stage, but after this works you can then install VSCode and see if the same problem exists. This is like a new setup of node, angular cli and VSCode.